# Errors in Android project

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm having problems working my way through an old tutorial, essentially i'm trying to pull the data returned in JSON format from www.amazingjobs.co.uk/app/marc/api/candidates/ into a listview.

I literally started learning android/java 24 hours ago so its likely it may be very simple but I just can't quite seem to figure it out, lines with errors are in bold!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Searchjobs extends Activity {
    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://www.amazingjobs.co.uk/app/marc/api/candidates/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
    // Jobs JSONArray
    JSONArray jobs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchjobs);
        Button Searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Searchbutton);
        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener(searchClick);
    }

    private OnClickListener searchClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          // Hashmap for ListView
              ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> JobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
              // Creating JSON Parser instance
              JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
              // getting JSON string from URL
              JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.amazingjobs.co.uk/app/marc/api/candidates/");
              // Getting Array of Contacts
             try {
                jobs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < jobs.length();i++){
                    JSONObject j = jobs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = j.getString("job_title");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("Title", title);

                    JobList.add(map);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             **ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, JobList,R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { "Title" }, new int[] {R.id.title});**
             **ERROR: The constructor SimpleAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){}, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined**

                **setListAdapter(adapter);
The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**

                // selecting single ListView item
                **ListView lv = getListView();**
                    **ERROR: The method getListView() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**


                 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                         int position, long id) {

                 }
             });

        };
    };
```

EDIT Ok new code is below, errors are, which seems odd because the activity errors relate to an activity that definately exists, have tried restart/clean in eclipse too.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
activity_searchjobs cannot be resolved or is not a field    Searchjobs.java /AmazingJobs/src/app/android/amazingjobs    line 47 Java Problem
activity_searchjobs cannot be resolved or is not a field    Searchjobs.java /AmazingJobs/src/app/android/amazingjobs    line 105    Java Problem
Searchbutton cannot be resolved or is not a field   Searchjobs.java /AmazingJobs/src/app/android/amazingjobs    line 48 Java Problem
list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field  Searchjobs.java /AmazingJobs/src/app/android/amazingjobs    line 83 Java Problem

```
public class Searchjobs extends ListActivity {
    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://www.amazingjobs.co.uk/app/marc/api/candidates/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
    // Jobs JSONArray
    JSONArray jobs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchjobs);
        Button Searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Searchbutton);
        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener(searchClick);
    }

    private OnClickListener searchClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          // Hashmap for ListView
              ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> JobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
              // Creating JSON Parser instance
              JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
              // getting JSON string from URL
              JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.amazingjobs.co.uk/app/marc/api/candidates/");
              // Getting Array of Contacts
             try {
                jobs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < jobs.length();i++){
                    JSONObject j = jobs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = j.getString("job_title");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("Title", title);

                    JobList.add(map);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplication(), JobList,R.layout.list_item,
                     new String[] { "Title" }, new int[] {R.id.title});

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                // selecting single ListView item
                ListView lv = getListView();

                 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                         int position, long id) {

                 }
             });

        };
    };
```

Comment: Put your error log here so i can find what the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, JobList,R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { "Title" }, new int[] {R.id.title});
```

should be changed to:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), JobList,R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { "Title" }, new int[] {R.id.title});
```

Second,

ListView lv = getListView();

will be resolved if you extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: Ah superb thanks, not that i'm ungrateful but what about the other two errors?

Comment: Brilliant, i've moved from PHP so Java is giving me complete brain ache getting to grips with it, thank you so much for your help theres no way I can split points between you?

Comment: You can accept only one answer, but you may upvote both if you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend `ListActivity` not `Activity` to make methods like `getListView()` avaialable or just replace it with `findViewById()` if you do not want to use ListActivity (it's not mandatory).